# Angular 2 how to resolve promise manually?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, promise

How would be possible to resolve a promise in Angular 2 inside a directive? I am trying to do a simple image loading directive:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[carouselImage]',
    host: {
        '(load)' : 'onImageLoad()'
    }
})
class CarouselImageDirective {
    private _promise: Promise;
    private _loaded: boolean = false;

    constructor(private _elRef: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer) {

    }

    loadImage() {
        this._promise = new Promise<ElementRef>( resolve => {
            resolve(this._elRef);
        });

    }

    onImageLoad() {
        this._promise.resolve(); //this won't work
        this._loaded = true;
        console.log('Image loaded ', this._elRef);
    }
}
```

My attempt so far does not work.

Comment: Have you tried `Promise.resolve(this._promise);`?

Comment: @echonax not working

Comment: What are you trying to do? You don't resolve promises, *they* resolve themself.

Comment: @dfsq  promises does not resolve themself, there is always a point that resolves them. I am trying to do just a simple image loader, detect when an images has been loaded. Any ideas/best practice?

Comment: I know how promises work. I worded it poorly, anyway glad you found a solution. Although it's still not very clear what you need this promise for in your directive, I mean you already have onload event.

Comment: I am doing a carousel in Angular2, so I need to know when all images are loaded before starting animations. From the image directive I just return a promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like that:

```
loadImage() {
    this._promise = new Promise<ElementRef>( resolve => {
        this.resolve = resolve;
    });

}

onImageLoad() {
    this.resolve(this._elRef);
    this._loaded = true;
    console.log('Image loaded ', this._elRef);
}
```

Comment: This is working nice, although I would have preferred the echonax solutions. Thank you